# Networking tags

Tags: discussion, tags

We've got kind of a set of network-related tags going, each with low question counts:

[networking](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking) - Some of these are port forwarding or connection issues, but a fair chunk appear to be about "lag" or "ping"

[lag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lag) - A fair bit of these seem to reference "ping"

[ping](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ping) - A fair bit of these seem to reference "lag"

For the purposes of tags on gaming.se, does it make sense to have these as separate tags?  There's perhaps 50 total, and I think if you were searching or trying to tag, they'd all be pretty relevant.  I'm aware that lag != ping != latency (although there's some level of overlap) but it seems like having just one "networking" tag might be a better option, given the low frequency of those types of questions.

Would it make sense to make [lag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lag) and [ping](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ping) synonyms for [networking](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking)?

Comment: I think they could be combined.

Comment: [tag:ping] and [tag:lag] are now one and the same

Comment: @badp, what of networking?  Any interest in consolidating further, or does it just make sense to go back and retag the ping related questions in that category?

Comment: @agent86 I need to think about it, hence why I posted it as a comment and didn't mark status completed.

Comment: @badp, acknowledged, roger that, 10-4 good buddy, understood.  Gotcha, is what I'm trying to say here.

Comment: Roger wilco, alpha gamma eighty six, roger wilco.